# VS Code emmet being very slow?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently using VS Code and the emmet extension snippet popup thing is being really slow, I don't understand this seeing as it was the same on my old pc now my new one, despite vs code being installed on my solid state drive, any help would be great :)

https://gyazo.com/3c695396fac1f14a826cc0da2300919b <-- video of it being slow! (only takes around 4 seconds but its really irritating)

Comment: for very big files the parsing can take some time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

VS -> settings -> search "Emmet" to scroll bottom

Emmet: show Expanded Abbreviation - never.

Emmet: Trigger Expansion on tab - "Checked"

Comment: Thank you so much, my emmet completion was very sluggish for a couple of months now and this fixed the issue.